# Permissions Sharepoint online

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a user ex: John Doe in which has changed is name, instead of John Doe it will be called John Don.

Two accounts exists on AD, already Synced,and my question is: how can i move permissions from Doe to Don?

Move-SPUser is good to do that? It is same domain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Move-SPUser is good for that. below is description from documentation for your quick reference.

Description
The Move-SPUser cmdlet migrates user access from one domain user account to another. If an entry for the new login name already exists, the entry is marked for deletion to make way for the migration.

Powershell

```
 C:\PS>$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -Web http://webUrl
    C:\PS>Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith" -IgnoreSid
```

This example migrates DOMAIN\JaneDoe to the new account of DOMAIN\JaneSmith.

Reference link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps